# SparkAR javascript toFixed(1) is not work

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

Here's the relevant code.

"counter.text = scorestring.toFixed(1).toString();"

I am not sure the code below is correct.

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');

Promise.all([
    
    Scene.root.findFirst('number'),
    Patches.outputs.getScalar('score'),
    Scene.root.findFirst('timer'),
    Patches.outputs.getScalar('timer_sec')

]).then(function(results){
    var counter = results[0];
    var scorestring = results[1];
    var counter2 = results[2];
    var timerstring = results[3];

    counter.text = scorestring.toFixed(1).toString();

    counter2.text = timerstring.toString();
})
```

SparkAR preview:

[image: screen of SparkAR preview]

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? Is the program crashing, or is the output you receive simply not what you expected? Including examples of what you want vs what actually happened is generally very helpful to those who wish to assist.

Comment: I just added a screen cap of the sparkAR preview, all texts becomes 0000. thanks.

Comment: If `scorestring` (as its name suggests) is actually a string, then `.toFixed` will not work because `.toFixed` works only on number values; a string does not provide that function. Then, assuming you do have a number or create one, it should be noted that `.toFixed(1)` already returns a string, so doing another `.toString()` after that is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

ScalarSignal class should be formatted with:

```js
format(formatString: string): StringSignal
```

The formatString rules as specified here: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Format.md#format-string-syntax .

In your scenario:

```js
counter.text = scorestring.format("You can also add text here {:.1f}");
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error "Property 'text' does not exist on type 'SceneObjectBase'." when I try to merge my scene with the patch. Please help me

Comment: @PrabhashiBuddhima this is not related to original question. You need to make your own with proper explanation.